# Binomial distribution from urn model

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

I'm trying to derive the binomial distribution function in terms of balls in an urn.

Say the urn has a total number of $N$ balls, where $K$ of them are green and $N-K$ of them are red. Thus the probability of selecting a green ball is $\frac{K}{N}$ and the probability of selecting a red ball is $\frac{N-K}{N}$. Now, say I select $n$ balls with replacement. The number of green balls in my selection will follow a binomial distribution, with probability mass function
$$
p(k; n) = \binom{n}{k} \Big(\frac{K}{N}\Big)^k \Big(\frac{N-K}{N}\Big)^{n-k}.
$$
Expanding the binomial coefficient and multiplying the factors in the denominator, this can be rewritten as
$$
p(k; n) = \frac{K^k (N-K)^{n-k} n!}{N^n k! (n-k)!}.
$$
Now, my question is: how should this be interpreted combinatorially? I sort of understand the numerator as selecting $k$ green balls and $n-k$ red balls with replacement, then ordering the whole selection, yielding the number of favorable outcomes. But what about the denominator?

Can anyone give me some insight on this?

Comment: The factorials in the denominator account for the overcounting in the numerator of reorderings of the balls of each color (which are already ordered by the selection process). Leaving the $\binom nk$ unexpanded makes it clearer.

Comment: Okay, so if I leave it as $\frac{K^k (N-K)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}}{N^n}$, the numerator can be interpreted as first selecting $k$ greens and $n-k$ reds, then ordering them up to permutation among same colors, right? How about $N^n$ then? Wouldn't that be ordered selections without replacement and not unordered?

Comment: Yeah - you get the order within each color from the selection process (the same way you get it in the denominator), so all that remains is to choose how to interleave the two ordered sequences, i.e. to choose $k$ out of $n$ positions for the green balls.

Comment: Ok, that makes total sense actually. I also see now how this would yield the formula for a hypergeometric distribution if we instead consider selections without replacement. Thank you so much!